# Set value in picklist visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce

How to set a picklist default value if I dont have a controller. I currently using standard controller account.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" showHeader="TRUE" label="Close Account" >
    <apex:sectionHeader subtitle="Account Closure" title=""/><br> </br>  
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Please Input Account Closure Date" >
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!Save}" />
                <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!Cancel}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <h1>Account Status: </h1>
              <br></br>
              <apex:inputField value="{!Account.Account_Status__c}" label="Status" required="TRUE"/>
              <h1>Account Closure Date: </h1>
              <br></br>
              <apex:inputField value="{!Account.Account_Closure_Date__c}" label="Close Date" required="TRUE"/>

        </apex:pageBlock>
        </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Yes. You can always JS to default/set the values. Is there a challenge to default the picklist value for the field or for a particular recordType.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you also don't want to use an extension class, you can add an ID to the `inputfield` and select it with Javascript.  Note that the ID in the ID attribute will be generated at the end of a larger ID, so you need to use the "ends with" selector (`$=`) to select the correct HTML element.

```
<apex:inputField value="{!Account.Account_Status__c}" label="Status" required="TRUE" id="accountStatus" />

<script>
    document.querySelector('[id$=accountStatus]').value = 'Default';
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I just wanna inquire also if there is a way to assign default value if the field is readonly on page. thanks for your help

Comment: I'm pretty sure this still works if it's readonly.